# How can i hide approve/rejection link in approver history using visualforce area in home page component?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, home-page-component

I am trying to hide approve/reject links using visualforce area but it is not happening below is the code and i have already included this page in home page component-

```
<apex:page standardController="Directory__c">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
        $(".SidebarShortcut").hide();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/jQuery">
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(
        alert("I am an alert box!");

        function() {
            if ($("a:contains('Approve')").length > 0 || $("a:contains('Reassign')").length > 0) {
                $("a").filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text() == "Approve / Reject";
                }).hide();
                $("a").filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text() == "Reassign";
                }).hide();
            }
        });
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: hmm looks like trying to access standard page links ? if Yes I suggest use `<apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps" ></apex:relatedList>` for accessing the link. else you can access because of cross origin policy

Comment: yaa...how can i use related list in visulaforce?

Comment: this is the code `<apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps" ></apex:relatedList>` add this code in your VF page

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Directory__c">
<apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps" >
 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("I am an alert box!");
$(".SidebarShortcut").hide(); 
}); 
 its not working?